# How to edit design of Solidus Commerce on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I wanted to know what is the best practice for theming Solidus Commerce, I know Spree 3 used Deface but I'm not really sure how to go about this with Solidus.

Do people simply bring in views, layouts and css files? Not sure if Deface will be extracted out or if that's not the best way to go.

Answer (score 1):

according to solidus community, Deface have been removed from the project.

please take a look at this ticket https://github.com/solidusio/solidus/issues/490